# Исключение при вызове метода MoveTo у экземпляра DirectoryInfo

Tags: c#, исключения, файловая-система, io

```
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
string s = @"C:\";
dir.MoveTo(s);
```

Текст в s для примера. Какой бы путь не вставил, исключение всё равно вылетает.

Исключение:

> "Процесс не может получить доступ к файлу, так как этот файл занят другим процессом."

Что не так? Вроде простейший код.

---

### UPD 24.03.16. 17.45.

Если кому-нибудь надо, могу выложить алгоритм поиска вверх по папкам.
Ищет в текущей папке нужную папку/файл/файлы с заданным расширением. Если не найдено, поднимается на уровень выше и ищет там, ещё выше и т. д. Опционально - поиск в подпапках, максимальное количество уровней "подъёма" вверх, название искомой директории, маска поиска файлов (одного файла или файлов с заданным расширением), папка начала поиска.
На выходе - путь к найденной папке. Поиск ленивый - до первой найденной папки, в которой есть искомые файлы.

Comment: Из текущей папки запущенно приложение, вот и не удается переместить её. По крайней мере - это то что приходит в голову в первую очередь.

Comment: @Monk опубликуйте в качестве ответа.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Из текущей папки запущенно приложение, вот и не удается переместить её.

По крайней мере - это то что приходит в голову в первую очередь.

Comment: Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() действительно возвращает рабочий каталог приложения, так что все верно. Подтверждение тут https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.directory.getcurrentdirectory(v=vs.110).aspx . Разумеется если текущий каталог не меняли в ручную.

Comment: Спасибо, до меня долго доходило. Думал, что DirectoryInfo - это нечто вроде указателя на папку, который можно изменять как угодно.

Comment: @rdorn поэтому при запуске из какого-нибудь FAR можно внезапно получить другую папку, иногда забавно так конфиги и логи обнаружить можно в других папках.